# Find best way to pair locations according to distance

Tags: php, sql

I need to be able to take a list of locations and determine the best way to pair them so that the distance between each location in the pair is the lowest

---

I have made a script that given a list of locations

1. Creates an array of unique pairings
2. For each pair it queries an API for the distance between that pair of locations

A list of 22 locations produces a list of 231 pairs.

Using this generated list which looks like:

```
address1, address2, dist
```

I need to find out the 11 best pairs where the distance between them is the lowest. Also this list must include all original 22 locations with each location only appearing once on the list.

**I am looking for a solution that employs either a SQL query, PHP or both

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add more details? Its not clear if you want to do find the pairs from the in memory PHP array or if you have those stored in DB(with API responses). Also the table structure would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. This solution looks at the shortest distances first and then only outputs that row if neither address1 or address2 have been used before.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    // Assigning variables from cell values
    $address1 = $row['address1'];
    $address2 = $row['address2'];

    if(in_array($address1, $minDistance) OR in_array($address2, $minDistance)) {

    } else {
        $minDistance[] = $address1;
        $minDistance[] = $address2;
        echo $row['address1'] . '|' . $row['address2'] . '|' . $row['distance'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty convoluted and it would be somewhat simpler if there were some sort of Id assigned to each row. You might consider doing that to simplify things, but with the data set as you gave it, this should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 11  x.*
    FROM    (SELECT r.address1
                            , MIN(r.dist) AS dist
                FROM    (SELECT   l.address1
                                , l.address2
                                , l.dist
                            FROM    locdist l
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT    l.address2 AS address1
                                , l.address1 AS address2
                                , l.dist
                            FROM    locdist l
                    ) r
                GROUP BY    r.address1
        ) y
        LEFT OUTER JOIN locdist x
            ON  x.dist = y.dist
                AND
                (x.address1 = y.address1
                OR
                x.address2 = y.address1)
    ORDER BY x.dist
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized just after posting the first time that it wasn't quite doing what you were asking. I believe this version should do the trick though.

Comment: This solution almost works but it does not restrict a location from appearing in more than one pair. Each location must be used in a pair and once a location is used in a pair it cannot be used again.

Comment: Ah, ya I guess it doesn't quite do what you asked does it... Well, I'm not exactly sure how I would solve that and it looks like you already have a solution, so I guess I won't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT address1, address2, dist, INSTR( @a , CONCAT( '--', address1 ) ) AS add1, INSTR( @a , CONCAT( '--', address2 ) ) AS add2, @a , @a := CONCAT( @a , '--', address1, '--', address2 )
FROM `data`
HAVING add1 =0
AND add2 =0
ORDER BY DIST
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

You can try this with your data, it should work.

Comment: you can limit the number of rows the way you want